# Creating an inner interface referencing a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define an interface inside a generic class, that uses the generic type in the outer class as part of its type.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Simple<T> {
  public interface Inner extends Function<? extends T,String>
  {
  }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
[ERROR] Simple.java:[5,52] non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
[ERROR] Simple.java:[5,34] unexpected type
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ? extends T
```

I can get rid of the second error with

```
public class Simple<T> {
  public interface Inner<T2 extends T> extends Function<T2,String>
  {
  }
}
```

but I am not able to figure out how to eliminate first error.  Is that possible or do I need to make `Inner` a top-level class

Comment: You can't do that nesting with an interface, as nested interfaces must be static.

Comment: How do you want to use this, that benefits from the type bound?